# Variable Name being read instead of its Value - @svelte-put/preprocess-inline-svg

Tags: svelte, svelte-preprocess

I am using [@svelte-put/preprocess-inline-svg](https://svelte-put.vnphanquang.com/docs/preprocess-inline-svg) to handle SVG's in my sveltekit app.

I have an array of strings that has all of my icon names in it.

Whenever trying to use:

```
<svg data-inline-src=${realIconList[3]} />
```

I get the error: `cannot find svg source for ${realIconList[3]}`

How do I get the variable's **value** to be read instead of its actual name?

Comment: Remove the `$` or wrap it in backticks, so that it's a template string? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?retiredLocale=de

Comment: @Corrl When I do that I get the error:  Expected value for the attribute

Comment: But if you set a name directly like `<svg data-inline-src="svelte" />` it works?

Comment: @Corrl Yeah it works if you explicitly state the name. That's how the package works. I just want to load a list of them